# 403 forbidden on rails + nginx + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I recently updated ubuntu on my server and since then have had a 403 forbidden. Here is the nginx.conf:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11016133

and here are the permissions on the rails/www directory:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11016213

Could really use some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of many reasons, please see this post and hopefully it would help you resolve your issue: http://thelazylog.com/posts/how-to-fix-403-fobidden-issue-on-nginx-rails-application